# Unexpected behavior of std::setw when used with std::stringstream

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
std::string n("123456");


std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::setw(3) << n;
std::cout << ss.str() << " | " << (ss.fail() ? "True" : "False") << std::endl;
```

Why does this print out

```
123456 | False
```

instead of

```
123 | False
```

Comment: I guess you might have misunderstood `setw`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw

Comment: The meaning of "setting the width" may not be clear, here's an explanation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effects of the width modifier are handled differently by different formatters. In the expression `ss << std::setw(3) << n`, where `n` has type `std:string`, you're using `operator<<(ostream&, const std::string&)`, which does the following (from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt)):

> a) If str.size() is not less than os.width(), uses the range
>   [str.begin(), str.end()) as-is

In your case, `str.size()` is `6` and `ss.width()` is `3`, so the entire string is output

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

Its perfectrly predicable behaviour:  [`setw()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)  sets the minimum width of the field.  If your output exceeds this length, it is written for its full length. By the way, the width will apply to all the following outputs until you change it again.

As it's only about formatting and as the ostream has no personal taste about bad alignemnt,  `fail()` will always return false ;-)

**Solution**

If your output is only strings, you have all the power of string [expression](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/):

```
ss << setw(3) << n.substr(0,3) ;   // set mini and maxi.
```

If you have a lot of such formatting, also with arithmetic types, you could consider writing a small adapter like the following:

```
template <class T>
string mfixed(ostream& os, T o, int n)
{
    stringstream ss; 
    ss.copyfmt(os);   // copy ALL format flags of ostream
    ss << setw(n)<< o;    // set the fixed length and ouput
    return ss.str().substr(0, n);  // truncate
}
```

You can use it very flexibly in your code:

```
ss << mfixed(ss, n, 3) 
    << " " << mfixed(ss, 25, 4) << " " << mfixed(ss, 100000, 3) 
    << " " << setprecision(2) << mfixed(ss, 1.0/3.0, 4);
```